# How did the treasure finally end up on Isla De Muerta?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl

In *Pirates of the Caribbean*, after Hernán Cortes further continued the killings on the Aztec empire, did he take the treasure or not? And how did the treasure finally end up on Isla De Muerta?

Comment: Barbossa and crew might have put them in there since Isla de muerte is their treasure hiding place. and if Cortes took that treasure, it couldn't be in possession of pirates innit?

Comment: @Vishwa while that seems to be a reasonable answer, the other issue is that the Island seems to disappear and go "all pear-shaped" after a hurricane comes post COTBP and besides being cursed the only other way to find it (so far) is with Jack's/Morgan's compass.

Comment: It's unclear if what happened with treasure (being magically restored/curse lifted) is related to the hurricane and/or if the hurricane is related to the magic of Tia Dalma, as she ends up with Barbossa's body. Is the Island magical on it's own, is it only magical, because of the treasure (possibly being originally "cursed" at this location), and/or is what happens after the first film separate and related to Tia Dalma/Calypso?

Comment: @DarthLocke - given how many times this movie almost didn't make it out of the gate, I doubt sequels were on anyone's mind. Don't get caught up trying to retcon an IP which from its inception was a cash grab.

Comment: @Mazura, I think it's besides the point, because it DOES have sequels and it has become a franchise that has an ongoing story with mythology. If everyone would have that perspective, then there would never be a need to ask a question like this. It's just it's hard to fully answer, because there are still unsolved mysteries and/or mythological points that haven't been perfectly specified.

Answer (score 1):

Not an official source but this should give you a ballpark idea of actual years when real world events happened versus fictional [timelines](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Pirates_of_the_Caribbean_series)

> c.1519
>
> - Hernán Cortés conquers the Aztec empire with his armies and wielding the Sword of Cortés.
> - The Aztecs deliver to Cortés a stone chest containing 882 identical pieces of Aztec gold, as blood money to appease his slaughter. When Cortés refuses to stop his conquest, the Heathen Gods place a curse upon the treasure, so that anyone who took but one coin from the chest would become undead skeletons. The treasure ultimately ended up on Isla de Muerta.
>
> 1728
>
> - James Norrington is promoted to the rank of Commodore. Jack Sparrow arrives in Port Royal prior to the Black Pearl's attack. Elizabeth Swann is kidnapped, and Will Turner recruits Jack to help save her. Jack assembles a crew at Tortuga, who set sail in the commandeered HMS Interceptor.
> - During the voyage to Isla de Muerta, Jack and his crew sack the Earl King, with Jack and Will posing as members of the Royal Navy.
> - Jack ultimately confronts Barbossa at Isla de Muerta. Turner lifts the curse, allowing Jack to kill Barbossa and his crew to be killed or captured by Norrington's men. Jack escapes a hanging with Will's help, and rejoins his crew. Will and Elizabeth pledge their love to one another. Jack the monkey takes a coin from the chest and becomes cursed once more.

There is roughly 200 years of history between the events of the Spanish conquest and the events of the first movie.  In 200 years of story, those coins exchanged many hands but the curse led Barbossa to gather them all at Isla de Muerta for the sake of the story.

Comment: Motive; dead men taste no apples. - "Find it, we did. There be the chest. lnside be the gold. And we took them all. We spent them and traded them and frittered them away on drink and food and pleasurable company. The more we gave them away, the more we came to realize, the drink would not satisfy, food turned to ash in our mouths, and all the pleasurable company in the world could not slake our lust. We are cursed men, Miss Turner. Compelled by greed, we were, but now we are consumed by it."

Comment: That's the entire plot of the movie in a single pontificated paragraph. The answers to almost any question you could have should be inferred from that quote. I would've sworn this was discussed standing in front of the chest; it's actually much earlier in the movie and establishes the plot of the endgame, and explains why no body cares about all the golden junk laying around, because for them it has long since lost its luster.